# How are defeated enemies counted?

Tags: super-mario-run

I noticed the defeated enemies count at the end of a level are not adding up.

I very carefully counted stomping on over 7 paratroopers. They went into their shells, stopped flying, and toppled off screen.

Is that not a "defeat?"

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had the same question. Apparently, stomping on the paratroopers and koopas and seeing them going into their shell, is not a "defeat." The only way to kill them normally is if they are hit with another shell, or you have a Star active.

Comment: I think if you roll through them that also counts. Will confirm later.

Comment: @Martin Ender You can't roll through enemies I don't believe.

Comment: you definitely can (I think it's even mentioned in the move list) and if you jump while rolling, the flip jump you do can also kill some enemies.

Comment: And sliding should also work.